# Compare and drop consecutive rows in a dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, comparison, rows

I need to compare two consecutive rows in a dataframe, for example:

df:

```
time        door       name
00:01:10    in         alex
00:01:10    in         alex
02:01:10    out        alex
03:01:10    in         alex
04:01:10    out        alex
04:01:10    out        alex
```

I need to remove duplicates if `door` is `in` (or `out`) in two consecutive rows.

This is a part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name='test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=0, index= False)
mydf = df.sort_values(by='time')
for i in range (len(mydf)):
    if (mydf[['door']] != mydf[['door']].shift(-1)).any(axis=1):
        print('ok')
    else:
        print ('nok')
```

I got this error:

```
if ((mydf[['Door Name']] != mydf[['Door Name']].shift(-1).any(axis=1))):

  File "C:\Users\khou\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I don't know how to fix it, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to get the index first, then delete based on index:

**Code**

```py
import pandas as pd

mydf=pd.DataFrame({'time':['00:01:10','00:01:10','02:01:10','03:01:10','04:01:10','04:01:10'],
                'door':['in','in','out','in','out','out'],
               'name':['alex','alex','alex','alex','alex','alex']})

idx=[]
for i in range (0,len(mydf)):
    if i == 0:
        print ('index '+str(i)+' ok')
    elif mydf['door'][i] != mydf['door'][i-1]:
        print('index '+str(i)+' ok')
    else:
        print ('index '+str(i)+' nok')
        idx.append(i)

mydf.drop(mydf.index[[idx]],inplace=True)

print('\n',mydf)
```

**Output**

```py
index 0 ok
index 1 nok
index 2 ok
index 3 ok
index 4 ok
index 5 nok

        time door  name
0  00:01:10   in  alex
2  02:01:10  out  alex
3  03:01:10   in  alex
4  04:01:10  out  alex
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.where` and then `dropna`

```
df['door'] = np.where((df['door'] == df['door'].shift(-1)), np.nan, df['door'])

df.dropna(how='any', axis=0, inplace= True)

print(df)

     time door  name
 00:01:10   in  alex
 02:01:10  out  alex
 03:01:10   in  alex
 04:01:10  out  alex
```

**Or**

and if there is always a duplicated time with door.values, then you can simply use `df.drop_duplicates` with parameters `keep = 'first' and subset = ['time', 'door']`

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['time', 'door'], keep='first', inplace= True)

print(df)

     time door  name
 00:01:10   in  alex
 02:01:10  out  alex
 03:01:10   in  alex
 04:01:10  out  alex
```

Comment: in the first method, when you print df you'll get an empty dataframe

Comment: @A.khou I used your given data and with that, it doesn't create empty dataframe. Not sure what kind of data you have. Try second option then.

Comment: I need the if condition because I need to check if door is in (or out) and the time difference between two rows is less than 5min then I'll drop duplicates

Comment: then please update the question or create new question with more clearer condition. Also, please post the expected output too.